# How To Change <a-sky> Color With Event Set Off By An Animation

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, webvr

My project basically is an assortment of blocks and the goal is to have the blocks rise on mouse hover as well as the "a-sky" component to change color to whatever color I set it too. Each cube will change the color of the sky to its color. Im having difficulty getting it to work. The first thing I tried was to set an animation to the a-sky component and have it begin with an event. Then I used Javascript in the block animation to set off the event when the block begins to hover. Here is what I have in the Glitch link below and the code is also below

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/b3c644bf-cbf9-4d26-80f4-cb6e5a00a556

```
 <!-- Sky -->
 <a-sky id="sky" color="beige" geometry="">
<a-animation attribute="color" begin="Normal" to="beige" dur="1000"></a-animation>
<a-animation attribute="color" begin="Orange" from="beige" to="#ff7400" dur="1000"></a-animation>
<a-animation attribute="color" begin="Dark-Yellow" from="beige" to="#ffe50a" dur="1000"></a-animation>
```

```
<!-- Orange Block -->
<a-box id="Orange-Box" color="#ff7400" navigate-on-click="url:http://google.com" position="0 1.5 -5" material="" geometry="">
    <a-animation attribute="position" from="0 1.5 -5" to="0 2.5 -5" begin="mouseenter">
    <script> document.querySelector('#sky').emit('Orange'); </script>
  </a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="position" from="0 2.5 -5" to="0 1.5 -5" begin="mouseleave">
    <script> document.querySelector('#sky').emit('Normal'); </script>
  </a-animation>
</a-box>

<!-- Dark Yellow Block-->
<a-box color="#ffe50a" position="2.5 1.5 -4" rotation="0 -33.11696055856158 0" material="" geometry="">
    <a-animation attribute="position" from="2.5 1.5 -4" to="2.5 2.5 -4" begin="mouseenter">
    <script> document.querySelector('#sky').emit('Dark-Yellow'); </script>
  </a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="position" from="2.5 2.5 -4" to="2.5 1.5 -4" begin="mouseleave">
    <script> document.querySelector('#sky').emit('Normal'); </script>
  </a-animation>
</a-box>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an event listener to the `<a-animation>` element to get the moment when the animation has ended

```
document.querySelector("#animation_component").addEventListener("animationend", (e) => {
  document.querySelector('#sky').emit('Normal');
})
```

Like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vphsb9go/).

Comment: Im sorry im not very good with Javascript at all. Could you show me exactly how to get the sky to change color using an event listener using my example please? Much appreciated !

Comment: @JohnAdegbuji [here](https://glitch.com/~unequaled-golf) you are, i tried to keep it to a minimum, i add the script at the end to be sure that all HTML elements can be grabbed with `document.querySelector`